# Druid controller - what is the correct way to "ignore" update

Tags: rust, druid-rs

In my rust druid application I need to filter the characters when they are non numeric and do not update the widget and associated field of my state structure. This is my code for the controller

```rust
struct NumericOnly;
impl Controller<String, TextBox<String>> for NumericOnly {
    fn update(&mut self, child: &mut TextBox<String>, ctx: &mut UpdateCtx, old_data: &String, data: &String, env: &Env) {

        if data.chars().enumerate().all(|(idx, chr)| chr.is_numeric() || (chr == '-' && idx == 0)) {
            child.update(
                ctx, old_data, data, env
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This is built on top of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544836/how-to-implement-callback-on-typing-in-textbox-with-rust-druid-not-lens-but-a) I got to a similar question long time ago.

Sadly now I face the issue where, while it doesn't update on non-numeric characters or '-' at any position but the first, once such "faulty" character is detected the widget seems to freeze. I assume that instead of completely ignoring the update I perhaps should've either used some dedicated functionality (which I didn't find any mention of), or update passing `old_data` as new data in `child.update()` call. Latter worked, but the unwanted characters started appearing in the text field.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to validate your user input. Have you looked at [`validate_partial_input`](https://docs.rs/druid/0.7.0/druid/text/format/trait.Formatter.html#tymethod.validate_partial_input) and [`validate_while_editing`](https://docs.rs/druid/0.7.0/druid/widget/struct.ValueTextBox.html#method.validate_while_editing)?

Comment: @Jmb from what i see now it looks like those 2 methods only available for Value Text Box rather then simple Text Box. I don't mind using the primer, but I don't understand the way to create formatter struct it takes in the ::new constructor. It has from trait, hence I assume it is not meant to be created by fields, but im not sure really.

Comment: also with a value text box it seems to be weird to even have the intermediary buff field in the app state, but I also don't know if there is a way to store the string somewhere else and put the converted value on "enter", or if I can validate-adjust-convert-assign at the same time.

Comment: in fact let me retract my previous statement - formatter from std::fmt was in scope hence the confusion.